# Upgrade to FSharp 3.1.2...Now query doesn't work?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I upgraded both my machine and my build machine to the latest FSharp 3.1.2. I'm using FAKE 3.2.17. Now I get this when the build runs:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Query' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The handle is invalid.

at System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(RuntimeMethodHandle handle)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.CallGenericStaticMethod(RuntimeMethodHandle methHandle)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.MakersCallers2(RuntimeMethodHandle FQ, RuntimeMethodHandle FE)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.MakeOrCallAverageByOrSumByGeneric[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i](Boolean isNullable, RuntimeMethodHandle fq_double, RuntimeMethodHandle fq_single, RuntimeMethodHandle fq_decimal, RuntimeMethodHandle fq_int32, RuntimeMethodHandle fq_int64, RuntimeMethodHandle fe_double, RuntimeMethodHandle fe_single, RuntimeMethodHandle fe_decimal, RuntimeMethodHandle fe_int32, RuntimeMethodHandle fe_int64, RuntimeMethodHandle FE)
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-Core>.$Query..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.ForwardDeclarations.get_Query()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryBuilder.Run[T](FSharpExpr`1 q)
```

Here is the code it bombs on:

```
        let records = 
            query { 
                for row in table do
                    where (row.Val.Contains(fileName))
                    select row
            }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: is fileName coming from another assembly that allows a nullable string by chance?  I would guess it's grumping about filename possibly being null

Comment: Great thought. It's not coming from another assembly and I've confirmed fileName has a value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling 3.1.2 and reinstalling it on the build machine.